# Покритикуйте код игры Камень-Ножницы-Бумага

Tags: python, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Помогите начинающему в Python - пример кода игры Камень-ножницы-Бумага. Хотел бы избавиться от global аргументов и вообще какие могут быть советы по оптимизации. С ООП еще толком не знаком. Еще не нравится присваивание начальных значений.

Вот пример:

```
import random
CountD = 0 # Счетчики - Ничья, Победа, Проигрыш (Draw, Loose, Win)
CountL = 0
CountW = 0
l = ['k','n','b'] # Значения для рандомной выборки - Камень, Ножницы, Бумага

def inp(): # ввод числа раундов
    global n
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Введите количество игр n '))
            return n
        except ValueError:
            print('Это не число!')


def logic(x, y): # логика игры
    global CountD, CountW, CountL
        if x == y:
            print('Ничья')
            CountD += 1
        elif (x == 'k' and y == 'n') or (x == 'n' and y == 'b') or (x == 'b' and y == 'k'):
            print('Выигрыш')
            CountW += 1
        else:
            print('Проигрыш')
            CountL += 1      
        return CountD, CountL, CountW

# Поехали!
inp()
while n != 0:
    while True:
        x = input('Камень (k), Ножницы (n), Бумага (b)')
        if x not in l:
            print('Введите k, n, b')
        else: break

    y = random.choice(l)
    logic(x, y)
    n -= 1
else:
    print('Победы - {0}\nПроигрыши - {1}\nНичьи- {2}'.format(CountW, CountL, CountD))
```

В дальнейшем думаю припилить простенький AI, чтобы "ловить" повторения хода игрока.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CountD = 0 # Счетчики - Ничья, Победа, Проигрыш (Draw, Loose, Win)
CountL = 0
CountW = 0
```

Ну первое что скажу в питоне принято именовать переменные с маленькой буквы разделяя их нижним подчеркиванием (`win_count`, `lose_count`).

```
l = ['k','n','b'] # Значения для рандомной выборки - Камень, Ножницы, Бумага
```

Константы так же но в верхнем регистре (`TYPE_LIST`). И какой смысл так сокращать имена? Тут никакой гонки нет по символам. Должно быть понятно самому программисту что там за объект. Иначе тебе придется комментировать весь свой код.

Для констант списка имеется специальный объект `turple`, который работает как же как `list` за исключением того, что его нельзя изменять и тем самым весит он на много меньше.

```
TYPE_LIST = ('stone', 'scissors', 'paper')
```

Так же можно заменить на `Enum`:

```
class GameType(enum.Enum):
    STONE = 0
    SCISSORS = 1
    PAPER = 2
```

Далее не понятно зачем у Вас возвращаются глобальные переменные. Эту строчку можно просто удалить.

```
return CountD, CountL, CountW
```

и эту

```
return n
```

всю логику запуска скрипта желательно вынести в условие `__name__ == '__main__'`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Поехали!
    inp()
    while n != 0:
    # ------
    # Остальной код
```

Это означает, что этот блок выполнится только в том случае, если этот скрипт был основным при запуске.
Это нужно, чтобы если вдруг Вам понадобилась переменная или функция из этого скрипта, то когда Вы импортируете этот файл и повторно эти функции не выполнятся.

Так же я бы предложил создать отдельный класс для игры

```
class Game:
   TYPES = ('stone', 'scissors', 'paper')

   def __init__(self):
       #: WIN, LOSE, DRAW
       counts = 0, 0, 0
       num = 0

   def increase_count(self, n):
       counts[n] += 1

   def round_logic():
       if self.user_choice == self.ii_choice:
           print('Ничья')
           self.increase_count(2)
       elif (self.user_choice == 'k' and self.ii_choice == 'n') 
               or (self.user_choice == 'n' and self.ii_choice == 'b')
               or (self.user_choice == 'b' and self.ii_choice == 'k'):
           print('Выигрыш')
           self.increase_count(0)
       else:
           print('Проигрыш')
           self.increase_count(1)

   def round(self):
       while True:
           self.user_choice = input('Камень (k), Ножницы (n), Бумага (b)')
           if self.user_choice not in Game.TYPES:
               print('Введите k, n, b')
           else:
               break

       self.ii_choice = random.choice(Game.TYPES)
       self.round_logic()

       self.num -= 1
       if self.num is 0:
           self.end()

   def end():
       print('Победы - {0}\nПроигрыши - {1}\nНичьи- {2}'.format(*self.counts)

   @staticmethod
   def start():
       while True:
           try:
               n = int(input('Введите количество игр n '))
               return Game(n)
           except ValueError:
               print('Это не число!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game.start()
```

Comment: Буду разбираться с циклами - у меня почему-то без явного возврата глобальных переменных все зацикливается. Спасибо за советы по оформлению!

Comment: Лучше вообще не использовать глобальные переменные таким образом. Создайте класс и всю логику делайте в нем.

Comment: Разобрался, убрал их явный возврат  - в любом случае буду пробовать класс (в процессе изучения) - уже читал что их лучше так не использовать. Спасибо!

Comment: while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Введите количество игр n '))
            return n

зацикливается потому что просто return нужно оставить... Прошу прощения это я не доглядел, когда посоветовал удалить строчку.

Comment: я там убрал весь "return n", а просто break в конце цикла вставил, и просто return работает, так что оба Ваших предложения верны. Спасибо. Классы пока немного пугают, будем пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif (self.user_choice == 'k' and self.ii_choice == 'n') 
               or (self.user_choice == 'n' and self.ii_choice == 'b')
               or (self.user_choice == 'b' and self.ii_choice == 'k'):
```

Надо заменить на:

```
elif self.user_choice + self.ii_choice in {'kn', 'nb', 'bk'}:
```